# Upload file to S3 Bucket with AWS SDK NoSuchBucket error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

Tried to upload file to S3 Bucket, i set up the SDK using the following code:

```
<?php

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

try {

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
        'region'  => 'us-east-1',
        'version' => 'latest',
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => "KEY",
            'secret' => "SECRET",
        ]
    ]);

    $result = $s3->putObject([
        'Bucket' => 'bucketname',
        'Key'    => 'test.txt',
        'SourceFile' => 'test.txt'
    ]);

    var_dump($result);

} catch (\Throwable $th) {
    echo $th;
}
```

> Error log

```
AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/test.txt` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response: NoSuchBucketThe specified bucket does not exist
```

> Possible errors:

The URL should be this form based on:
[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html)

```
https://s3.Region.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/key name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the trouble is with the `S3 Client` itself. Below is the example from the documentation [PutObject.php](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/php-s3-PutObject.php.html)

```php
use Aws\S3\S3Client;  
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
....
try {
    //Create a S3Client
    $s3Client = new S3Client([
        'profile' => 'default',
        'region' => 'us-west-2',
        'version' => '2006-03-01'
    ]);
    $result = $s3Client->putObject([
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key' => $key,
        'SourceFile' => $file_Path,
    ]);
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

Comment: The profile is just switching to another key/secret pair, but i use the hardcode credentials, more here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials_profiles.html

Comment: @X11 still [Using Hard-Coded Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials_hardcoded.html), check in the link, how the constructor is getting initialized and add a check for the bucket existence by [headbucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#headbucket)

Comment: I got: "resulted in a `404 Not Found` response NotFound" from headbucket

Comment: @X11 then double your bucket presence via the command-line [aws-cli s3 ls](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/ls.html) using the credentials you have added in the script

Comment: I get: "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied" from aws cli calling aws s3 ls

Comment: @X11 in that case your credentials are not valid in that case, or you don't have permission on that. Check credentials or simply renew them via the console, check your user's permissions as well. Check if the bucket has bucket policy attached.

Comment: After setting up the credentials and created a new bucket, it's working now